# How to extract elements of variable names using grep in R

Tags: r, extract

I have variable names in the form `A_B_C_D`. I would like to extract anything that appears after the second `_`. So `C` and `D`, leaving out the underscore.

Can someone please help me do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
unlist(strsplit("A_B_C_D", "_"))[-(1:2)]

[1] "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into packages `stringr`. Alternatively, if you know that you *always* need the *second* `_`, just use `strsplit`.

```r
library(magrittr)
"A_B_C_D" %>% strsplit(., '_') %>% {.[[1]]} %>% {.[3:length(.)]}
```

```r
[1] "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex , `sub` and `gsub` -

```
x <- 'A_B_C_D'
gsub('_', '', fixed = TRUE, sub('.*?_.*?_', '', x))

#[1] "CD"
```